# which machine should be with more power?

Tags: performance

I have a VM machine that runs RoR.

Then, I have a second VM that runs MySql DB.

VM#1 calls VM#2 all the time.

Which machine should have the better CPU and performance?

Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, usually a database needs more resources than a web application, but the question really is too vague for us to adequately answer. You need to analyze the size of your DB, how many reads/sec and writes/sec are occurring, and much more.